# Connect IQ unexpected type Error when using setText

Tags: garmin, connectiq, monkeyc

When a menu item is pressed I want to set the text of a label, however i'm getting the errors: "Failed invoking <symbol>" and "Unexpected Type Error".

In my menu delegate I have:

```
using Toybox.WatchUi as Ui;
using Toybox.System as Sys;
using Toybox.Position as Position;

class DiscGolfMenuDelegate extends Ui.MenuInputDelegate {

    var _view;

    function initialize() {
        MenuInputDelegate.initialize();
        _view = new DiscGolfView();
    }

    function onMenuItem(item) {
        if (item == :measure_throw) {
            Sys.println("item 1");
            _view.setLongestThrow("yeet");
        } else if (item == :start_game) {
            Sys.println("item 2");
        }
    }

}
```

the setLongestThrowFunction is located in my View class and looks like:

```
function setLongestThrow(msg) {
    longest_throw_label.setText(msg);
}
```

It doesn't make sense why i'd get an unexpected type error as i'm passing through a string. Anyone see something I don't? thanks.

Comment: try to use ```longest_throw_label.setText(msg.toString())``` I know it looks stupid, and it does not make sense, but it can help.

Comment: `Failed invoking <symbol>` can either mean that you tried to call a method on a null object or your variable isn't the type you think it is. Print out the value of msg and the value of `_view` on different lines and see what they are (they should be something like `Obj: 51`) or which line crashes. That will likely answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is not with `_view` or the string passed to `setText`, but with `longest_throw_label`.

The issue is likely that you initialize `_view` in the menu constructor, but the view has not been laid out yet (the system hasn't called `_view.onLayout(dc)` because the view hasn't been pushed).